# LINQ Exception handling

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I 'm getting this error: An unhandled exception of type ***"System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DataReport.exe"*** in the linq query. Hereafter my code. Any idea how to handle this exception. Thanks.

```
private void btnFilterBy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var records = 
        from record in data.AsEnumerable()
        where (record.Field<string>(data.Columns[0].ColumnName).Contains(txtBC.Text) && 
               record.Field<string>(data.Columns[1].ColumnName).Contains(txtRM.Text) &&
               record.Field<string>(data.Columns[2].ColumnName).Contains(txtClient.Text) &&
               record.Field<string>(data.Columns[4].ColumnName).Contains(txtProduct.Text) &&
               record.Field<string>(data.Columns[7].ColumnName).Contains(txtSegment.Text) &&
               record.Field<string>(data.Columns[6].ColumnName).Contains(txtMonth.Text))
        select record;
    dataQuery = records.CopyToDataTable();
    dtGridPivot.DataSource = dataQuery;
}
```

Comment: check data columns length before your query

Comment: @Sayse: That would yield an `IndexOutOfRangeException`...

Comment: ah true... check data columns content :p  (`data.Columns.Any(x => x == null)`)

Comment: check if data is null & check if data has enough columns.. also you might want to code defensively(checking for null at each point) while getting ColumnName..

Comment: Are you sure `data` is not null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates one or more of the fields you are requesting are missing.  This is probably due to either the `data` object being null, or one of the `Columns` missing.

Try adding something like the following lines of code

```
if (data == null)
   throw new InvalidOperationException("Data is null");

if (data.Columns.Count < 8)
   throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid number of columns.");

// Casting as DataColumn - but cast as whatever is approperiate
if (data.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x == null || x.ColumnName == null))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Data values are missing or null.");


var records = 
    from record in data.AsEnumerable()
    where (record.Field<string>(data.Columns[0].ColumnName).Contains(txtBC.Text) && 
           record.Field<string>(data.Columns[1].ColumnName).Contains(txtRM.Text) &&
           record.Field<string>(data.Columns[2].ColumnName).Contains(txtClient.Text) &&
           record.Field<string>(data.Columns[4].ColumnName).Contains(txtProduct.Text) &&
           record.Field<string>(data.Columns[7].ColumnName).Contains(txtSegment.Text) &&
           record.Field<string>(data.Columns[6].ColumnName).Contains(txtMonth.Text))
    select record;
dataQuery = records.CopyToDataTable();
dtGridPivot.DataSource = dataQuery;
```

This will ensure that the column values being loaded, exist or throws a more meaningful exceptions.

Comment: I used the code, it doesn' catch the exception the compiler does, same as the first one. I'v checked again the data (origin file excel), there was 2 values missed ! from 29644 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I traditionally use the null coellescing operator `??` to check for nulls in my collections and `where` expressions to filter before selection, grouping or ordering